# Existence of specific transversal sections on the tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields

To define $\chi(M)$ for a manifold with boundary first we need to show the existence of an outward-pointing vector field that is transverse to the zero section , at least as Hirsch does it. Now I am trying to understand why said vector field exists. It's clear to me that outward-pointing sections exists, and by transversality we have that the set of maps from $M$ to $TM$ that are transversal to the zero section is open and dense. Now I don't see how I can put these two things together to get the existence of a section that is outward-pointing and transversal to the zero section.  I know I can find a section that is transverse to the zero section but this doesn't have to be outward-pointing.

Now in something similar that came up in my mind. Suppose we have a submanifold $N$ of $M$ of dimension $n-1$, is it possible to have a section that is tangent to $N$ at points of $N$ , where we make the canonical identifications with the inclusion map, such that this vector field is also transverse to the zero section of $M$? I thought  about using Parametric transversality to the normal bundle and to the zero section but that got me nowhere. I know I can build a vector field such that when restricted to $N$ is tangent to it but when I try to make it transversal to the zero section by approximation I could lose this property.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every time you want to post a question, you should first ask yourself if the extension theorem I told you about six differential topology questions ago might be the answer.

Comment: I have tried to use the homotopy extension theorem but I am not being able to get what I want. @TedShifrin

Comment: I think I have come up with a solution for the outward-pointing vector field transverse to the zero section, but doens't use the homotopy extension theorem, we just need to consider $f:M\rightarrow TM$ to be an outward-pointing vector field and then we can approximate it by $g$ that are transversal to the zero section and for $g$ close enough we get that $\pi\circ g$ is a diffeomorphism and so we can consider $g\circ (\pi \circ g)^{-1}$ and for $g$ close enough to $f$, g has to be outward-pointing, this I belive can be seen looking at the local representation of the vector field.